# Why using .bind() in an example of .reduce()

Tags: javascript

I was looking at this example of reduce() at https://putaindecode.io/articles/array-reduce-par-l-exemple/

```
var stats = [
  { site: "google.fr", browser: "Chrome", value: "50%" },
  { site: "google.fr", browser: "FireFox", value: "30%" },
  { site: "google.fr", browser: "Internet Explorer", value: "20%" },
  { site: "mozilla.fr", browser: "FireFox", value: "60%" },
  { site: "mozilla.fr", browser: "Internet Explorer", value: "20%" },
  { site: "microsoft.fr", browser: "Chrome", value: "10%" },
  { site: "microsoft.fr", browser: "FireFox", value: "20%" },
];

function compareSite(site, item) {
  return site === item.site;
}
function containSite(site, items) {
  return items.some(compareSite.bind(null, site));
}
function groupBySite(memo, item) {
  var site = memo.filter(containSite.bind(null, item.site));
  if (site.length > 0) {
    site[0].push(item);
  } else {
    memo.push([item]);
  }
  return memo;
}
// We use an empty array as accumulator 
var results = stats.reduce(groupBySite, []);

console.log(results);
```

and the result is:

```
[
    [
      { site: 'google.fr', browser: 'Chrome', value: '50%' },
      { site: 'google.fr', browser: 'FireFox', value: '30%' },
      { site: 'google.fr', browser: 'Internet Explorer', value: '20%' }
    ],
      { site: 'mozilla.fr', browser: 'FireFox', value: '60%' },
      { site: 'mozilla.fr', browser: 'Internet Explorer', value: '20%' }
    ],
    [
      { site: 'microsoft.fr', browser: 'Chrome', value: '10%' },
      { site: 'microsoft.fr', browser: 'FireFox', value: '20%' }
    ]
  ]
```

I don't understand some things:

Why in containSite function *".bind(null, site)"* is necessary? 
Why in groupBySite function *".bind(null, item.site)"* is used and not the previous *".bind(null, site)"*?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind#partially_applied_functions

Answer (score 1):

The author used the `bind` syntax to "prefill" the first argument of the passed function, much like below.

```js
function fn(a, b, c, d) {
  console.log({ a, b, c, d });
}

fn.bind(null, 1, 2)('c', 'd')
fn(1, 2, 'c', 'd');
```

Most people will not like you for using the first syntax, because most people will need to look up the exact usage of the bind...

Usually `bind` is used to change the value of `this` inside of the function passed to bind.

Answer (score 1):

As I know, `containSite` and `containSite2` are equivalent

```js
function compareSite(site, item) {
  return site === item.site;
}

function containSite(site, items) {
  return items.some(compareSite.bind(null, site));
}

function containSite2(site, items) {
  return items.some((items) => compareSite(site, items));
}
```

Usually `bind` is used to change `this` pointer inside function:

```js
function fn() { console.log(this) };
let binded_fn = fn.bind("Hello, World!"); // bind this with string "Hello, World!"
binded_fn(); // String {'Hello, World!'}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how do you come up with *"(items) => compareSite(site, items);"* in containSite2 function
<br>
I know arrow function
If we have a function:

const squareNum = (num) => {
  return num * num;
};

Comment: Not about arrow function, I just use it to simplify the syntax. I want to show you that the variable `site` has bound to the function `compareSite` and generate a new function.